# Trying to use CASE WHEN and ISNUMERIC

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I'm trying to validate a column 'id' in the table 'tableId', which has the following

```
|id|
12345678
0012345678
A12345
B12345
```

I'm trying to create a 2nd column called id2 which would be:

```
|id2|
12345678
12345678
A12345
B12345
```

So that I can know, after using COUNT + DISTINCT, that there are duplicates that just happen to have 0s left of the number, but are in fact the same IDs.

I tried to use CASE WHEN with ISNUMERIC and CAST as numeric, as some sort of error management that returns the same value (the ones that have a non-numeric character such as the last 2) in case it isn't numeric and, if it is, it'll cast it to numeric and return the numeric value without the 0s on the left. However, it returns the error

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

The code:

```
select id,
        case when ISNUMERIC(id)=0 then id else CAST(id as numeric) end as id2
        from tableId
```

In Excel I'd have used something like =IF(ISNUMBER(id),VALUE(id),id) , but I can't seem to get it right on SQL Server 2012.

Thanks in advance!

Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try_cast()` instead:

```
select id, TRY_CAST(id as numeric) id2
from tableId
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is it! I can't believe I missed this. This'll definitely help me out, thank you! Also, is sql server documentation enough to make the transition from using PL-SQL? I used to work with procedures and executes with PL-SQL, so I'm still trying to get used to SQL SERVER. If you have any resources it'd help me out greatly. Thanks and cheers from Peru!

Comment: @DiegoM . . . PL/SQL is much more powerful than T-SQL, so if you are really adept, you might have some frustrations (for example, the ability to have dynamic SQL in functions, packages, or generic types).  However, most tasks can be done in both environments and you'll just need to get used to the new environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to get distinct count

```
select count(distinct( 
   case when try_cast(ID as numeric) is null 
         then ID else cast(try_cast(ID as numeric) as char) end)) as New_ID  
from your_Table
```

Comment: Thank you, Prafulla! One thing, for some reason the cast as char part of the code without the count aggregator adds lots of spacing after each id record. Is there anyway to not have this?

Comment: You can try varchar instead of char. CHAR always uses the same amount of storage space per entry, while VARCHAR only uses the amount necessary to store the actual text.